# About sending messages and window message queues

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading, thread-safety, message-queue

About sending message and message queues, I'm very confused.

As we known, Posting Message will go into message queue, message pump will process the message in the queue one by one.

Sending message will directly go to a windows procedure. Is there any queue for sending messages?  For example, 10 background threads send message to UI thread, the message hander method in UI thread take long time to execute.

If this kind of sending message queue exists, message is processed one by one?

If this kind of message does not exist, i think any message is sent to UI thread,the message handler method should be push to stack immediately. Right?!

Comment: Worker threads should always use PostMessage() unless they send a system message.

Comment: Yes,you are right.but the question is we use CAB event,it sends message,not post to UI.